# trying to add number to number allready saved on label

Tags: ios, xcode

So I have a TextField integer that needs to be added to a label.

For example when I type 20, it appears in the label and when I save it and come back it's still there, so far so good right, i got this part down.

Now lets say I come back and want to add another amount to whats already there, to the 20.  how exactly would I go about doing it?

I used the `NSUserDefaults` to load/save the data but when I go to update the label I get stuck when trying to use my variables, say: `currentValue`, `valueToAdd` and `valueTotalAfterAddition`.

Comment: Could you show us some of the code that you have tried?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Or are you just unsure how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the `intValue` of the text, and then add whatever number. Example

```
int currentValue = textField.text.intValue;
int valueToAdd = 10; //change this to whatever you need
int valueTotalAfterAddition = currentValue + valueToAdd;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", valueTotalAfterAddition];
```

Comment: appreciate all the responses! ok I got... int valueToAdd (actual value input from the textfield). Then i got currentValue (int in label that will be added to the input from textfield. Finally after I hit enter the label will update with the sum ok. Now, after saving that sum, the next value from textfield its going to be added to that last sum... and so on and so forth. I'm so lost! i got one variable from the textfield but the other variable missing from the equation can not be zero after the first addition, so i can not initialized it as a zero.

Comment: i figured it out. i had the implementation in the wrong method. it should have been in the method for when the enter button was pressed in the keyboard!